# Selenium files error, i'm not able to import them correctly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

i have tried everything...stackoverflow is the final option

```
    from selenium import *
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    location = r"C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\webpage.html"
    driver.get(location)
```

Clicking on the "Alert" button to generate the Simple Alert

```
    button = driver.find_element_by_name('alert')
    button.click()
```

Switching the control to the Alert window

```
    obj = driver.switch_to.alert
```

Retrieving the message on the Alert window

```
    msg = obj.text
    print("Alert shows following message: "+ msg )
    
    time.sleep(2)
```

using the accept() method to accept the alert

```
    obj.accept()
    
    print(" Clicked on the OK Button in the Alert Window")
    
    driver.close
```

**Now heres the error**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\testing.py", line 4, in <module>
        from selenium import webdriver
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
        from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
        from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
        import urllib3
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .exceptions import (
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 199, in load_module
        mod = mod._resolve()
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 113, in _resolve
        return _import_module(self.mod)
      File "C:\Users\rehma\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "C:\Users\rehma\Downloads\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
        import email.parser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package
```

Comment: Please can you show all your imports.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is probably named email.py, change it to something different.

Comment: Great anticipation.